# Automatically generate TypeScript classes from database tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, postgresql

Made a project to generate TypeScript classes from database tables, and I'm looking for input if the code is reasonable. `pg` and `mysql` are not hard dependencies - that's why they're `@ts-ignore`d.

This would be my first package to be published in npm.

Goals were to have as little as possible dependencies and maximum flexibility. I'm planning to add support for callback mutators to different parts of the generator.

```
import {parse as urlParse} from 'url';

export enum DialectType
{
    PostgreSQL = 'postgres',
    MySQL = 'mysql'
}
enum ForceCase
{
    None = 'none',
    Camel = 'camel',
    Snake = 'snake',
    Pascal = 'pascal',
}

export interface Options
{
    excludeTables?: Array<string>
    schema?: string
    extends?: string | object
    dialect?: DialectType
    exportKeyword?: string
    attribute?: string
    indent?: string
    forceMemberCase?: ForceCase
    forceTypeCase?: ForceCase
    prepend?: string
    append?: string
    lineFeed?: string
    header?: boolean
    connectionData?: ConnectionData
    additional_info: any
}

let defaultOptions =
    {
        excludeTables: [],
        schema: 'public',
        extends: '',
        dialect: DialectType.PostgreSQL,
        exportKeyword: 'class',
        attribute: '',
        indent: '    ',
        forceMemberCase: ForceCase.None,
        forceTypeCase: ForceCase.None,
        prepend: '',
        append: '',
        lineFeed: '\n',
        header: true,
        additional_info: {},
    } as Options;

export interface Column
{
    name: string
    type: string
    nullable: boolean
}

export interface Table
{
    name: string
    columns: Array<Column>
}

export interface ConnectionDataObject
{
    user?: string;
    database?: string;
    password?: string;
    port?: number;
    host?: string;
    connectionString?: string;
}

type ConnectionData = string | ConnectionDataObject;

type DBColumn = { column_name, data_type, is_nullable };

type ITransformColumn = ((column: DBColumn) => Column);

type QueryResult = { rows: Array<any>, error: any };

interface IClient
{
    query: ((string) => Promise<QueryResult>)
    options: Options
}

class Dialect
{
    connectionData: ConnectionData;
    options: Options;

    constructor(connectionData, options)
    {
        this.connectionData = connectionData;
        this.options = options;
    }

    protected client: IClient;
    protected real_client: any;

    //abstract transformColumn(column: DBColumn): Column;

    getClient(): Promise<IClient>
    {
        return null;
    }

    getMapping(): { [type: string]: Array<string>; }
    {
        return null
    }

    mapColumn(column_type: string): string
    {
        let type = 'any';
        let mapping = this.getMapping();
        for (let t in mapping)
        {
            if ((mapping[t] as Array<string>).indexOf(column_type) !== -1)
            {
                type = t;
                break;
            }
        }
        return type;
    }

    transformColumn(column: DBColumn): Column
    {
        let name = column.column_name;
        name = Generator.camelCase(name);
        return {
            name: name,
            type: this.mapColumn(column.data_type),
            nullable: column.is_nullable === 'YES',
        }
    }
    async getTableNames()
    {
        let client = await this.getClient();
        return (await client.query(`
            select distinct table_name 
            from information_schema.columns 
            where table_schema = '${this.options.schema}'
        `)).rows.map(row => row.table_name);
    };
}

export class PostgresDialect extends Dialect
{
    async getClient()
    {
        if (this.client) return this.client;
        // @ts-ignore
        let pg = await import('pg');
        let client = this.real_client = new pg.Client(this.connectionData);

        await client.connect();
        this.options.additional_info.ip = (client as any).connection.stream.remoteAddress;
        return this.client = {
            async query(statement)
            {
                let res = (await client.query(statement));
                return {
                    rows: res.rows,
                    error: res.errno
                };
            }
        } as IClient;
    }

    getMapping()
    {
        return {
            number: ['int2', 'int4', 'int8', 'float4', 'float8', 'numeric', 'money', 'oid'],
            string: ['bpchar', 'char', 'varchar', 'text', 'citext', 'uuid', 'bytea', 'inet', 'time', 'timetz', 'interval', 'name'],
            boolean: ['bool'],
            Object: ['json', 'jsonb'],
            Date: ['date', 'timestamp', 'timestampz'],

        };
    }


}

export class MySQLDialect extends Dialect
{
    async getClient()
    {
        if (this.client) return this.client;
        // @ts-ignore
        let mysql = await import('mysql');
        let client = mysql.createConnection(this.connectionData);

        await new Promise<void>( resolve => { client.connect(resolve) });

        this.options.additional_info.ip = (client as any)._socket.remoteAddress;
        let query = function promise_query(q) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                client.query(q, ((err, results) => {
                    resolve({
                        rows: results,
                        error: err
                    })
                }))
            })
        };
        if (typeof this.connectionData === 'string')
        {
            this.options.schema = urlParse(this.connectionData).pathname.substr(1)
        }

        return this.client = {
            query: query
        } as IClient;
    }

    getMapping()
    {
        return {
            number: ['integer', 'int', 'smallint', 'mediumint', 'bigint', 'double', 'decimal', 'numeric', 'float', 'year'],
            string: ['char', 'varchar', 'text', 'tinytext', 'mediumtext', 'longtext', 'time', 'geometry', 'set', 'enum'],
            boolean: ['tinyint'],
            Object: ['json'],
            Date: ['date', 'datetime', 'timestamp'],
            Buffer: ['tinyblob', 'mediumblob', 'longblob', 'blob', 'binary', 'varbinary', 'bit'],

        };
    }

}

class Generator
{
    protected static indent = '    ';
    options: Options;
    constructor(options: Options)
    {
        this.options = options;
    }
    static camelCase(text: string)
    {
        return text.split(/[^a-z]/i).filter(x => x).map( (v, i) => {
            return i ? v.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + v.substr(1) : v;
        }).join('');
    }
    protected getHost()
    {
        if(this.options.connectionData)
        {
            if(typeof this.options.connectionData === 'string')
            {
                return urlParse(this.options.connectionData).host
            }
            else
            {
                return this.options.connectionData.host;
            }
        }
        return '';
    }
    generateType(column: Column)
    {
        return column.type + (column.nullable ? ' | null' : '');
    }
    generateClass(table: Table)
    {
        let o = this.options;
        let lf = o.lineFeed;
        let output = '';
        let inheritance = o.extends ? ` extends ${o.extends}` : '';
        let attribute = o.attribute ? o.indent + o.attribute + lf : '';
        output += `export ${this.options.exportKeyword} ${table.name}${inheritance}${lf}{${lf}`;
        table.columns.map(column => {
            output += attribute;
            output += `${o.indent}${column.name}: ${this.generateType(column)};${lf}`;
        });
        output += '}';
        return output;
    }
    generateTables(tables: Table[])
    {
        let o = this.options;
        let lf = o.lineFeed;
        let lflf = lf + lf;
        let output = '';
        if(o.header)
        {
            let cleanOptions = Object.assign({}, o);
            delete cleanOptions['connectionData'];
            let header = [
                `Generated on ${(new Date()).toISOString()}`,
                'Host: ' + this.getHost(),
                //'Tables: ' + tables.map(t => t.name).join(', '),
                'Options used:'
            ].concat(JSON.stringify(cleanOptions, null, o.indent).replace('*/', '*//*').split('\n'));

            output += '/**\n * ' + header.join(lf + ' * ') + lf + ' * ' + lf + ' */' + lflf;
        }
        if(o.prepend)
        {
            output += o.prepend + lflf;
        }

        output += tables.map(table => this.generateClass(table)).join(lflf);

        if(o.append)
        {
            output += lflf + o.append;
        }
        return output;
    }
}

export async function grease(connectionString: string | ConnectionData, options: Options = null, generatorClass: typeof Generator = Generator)
{
    options = Object.assign(defaultOptions, options || {});

    let CurrentDialect: typeof Dialect;

    switch (options.dialect)
    {
        case DialectType.PostgreSQL:
            CurrentDialect = PostgresDialect;
            break;
        case DialectType.MySQL:
            CurrentDialect = MySQLDialect;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error('No dialect specified');
    }

    let dialect = new CurrentDialect(connectionString, options);
    let client = await dialect.getClient();

    async function columns(table: string)
    {
        if (options.dialect == DialectType.MySQL)
        {
            return (await client.query(`
                select column_name, data_type, is_nullable
                from information_schema.columns
                where table_schema = '${options.schema}' and table_name = '${table}'
            `));
        }
        else
        {
            return (await client.query(`
                select column_name, udt_name as data_type, is_nullable
                from information_schema.columns
                where table_schema = '${options.schema}' and table_name = '${table}'
            `));
        }
    }

    let table_names = await dialect.getTableNames();

    let table_promises = [];

    let tables: any = [];

    for (let i in table_names)
    {
        let promise = columns(table_names[i]);
        table_promises.push(promise);
        promise.then(result => {
            tables.push({
                name: table_names[i],
                raw_columns: (result.rows as Array<DBColumn>),
                columns: (result.rows as Array<DBColumn>).map(col => dialect.transformColumn(col))
            })
        });
    }
    await Promise.all(table_promises);

    let generator = new generatorClass(options);
    let all = generator.generateTables(tables);
    return all;
}
```

Used like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

import {parse as urlParse} from 'url';
import {grease} from "../src/elbowgrease";
import * as fs from 'fs'


let connectionData = process.argv.slice(-2, -1)[0];
let output = process.argv.slice(-1)[0];
let args = process.argv.slice(2, -2);
let options = {} as any;
let config = 'elbowgrease.json';

args.map(arg => {
    let option = /--([a-zA-Z]+)=(.*)/.exec(arg);
    if (option[1] === 'config')
    {
        config = option[2];
    }
    else
    {
        options[option[1]] = option[2];
    }
});

if (fs.existsSync(config))
{
    options = Object.assign(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(config, 'utf8')), options);
}

if('connectionData' in options)
{
    connectionData = options.connectionData;
}
if('output' in options)
{
    output = options.output;
}
if(typeof connectionData === 'string')
{
    options.dialect = urlParse(connectionData).protocol.slice(0,-1);
}


grease(connectionData, options).then(outputCode => {
    fs.writeFileSync(output, outputCode);
    process.exit();
});
```